# Why SELECT N + 1 with no foreign keys and LINQ?

Tags: linq, foreign-keys, select-n-plus-1

I have a database that unfortunately have no real foreign keys (I plan to add this later, but prefer not to do it right now to make migration easier). I have manually written domain objects that map to the database to set up relationships (following this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects), and I've finally gotten the code to run properly. However, I've noticed I now have the SELECT N + 1 problem. Instead of selecting all Product's they're selected one by one with this SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [ProductID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[info] AS [Description] 
FROM [products] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[id] = @p0 
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [65]
```

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        var cat = categoriesRepository.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.LocalizedCategories).Where(lc => lc.CountryID == 1).First(lc => lc.Name == category).Category;
        var productsToShow = cat.Products;
        var viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = productsToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = productsToShow.Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = cat
        };
        return View("List", viewModel);
    }
```

Since I wasn't sure if my LINQ expression was correct I tried to just use this but I still got N+1:

```
var cat = categoriesRepository.Categories.First();
```

Domain objects:

```
[Table(Name = "products")]
public class Product
{
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "info")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private EntitySet<ProductCategory> _productCategories = new EntitySet<ProductCategory>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_productCategories", OtherKey = "productId", ThisKey = "ProductID")]
    private ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories; }
        set { _productCategories.Assign(value); }
    }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return (from pc in ProductCategories select pc.Category).ToList(); }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "products_menu")]
class ProductCategory
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "products_id")]
    private int productId;
    private EntityRef<Product> _product = new EntityRef<Product>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_product", ThisKey = "productId")]
    public Product Product
    {
        get { return _product.Entity; }
        set { _product.Entity = value; }
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "products_types_id")]
    private int categoryId;
    private EntityRef<Category> _category = new EntityRef<Category>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_category", ThisKey = "categoryId")]
    public Category Category
    {
        get { return _category.Entity; }
        set { _category.Entity = value; }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "products_types")]
public class Category
{
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    private EntitySet<ProductCategory> _productCategories = new EntitySet<ProductCategory>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_productCategories", OtherKey = "categoryId", ThisKey = "CategoryID")]
    private ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories; }
        set { _productCategories.Assign(value); }
    }

    public ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get { return (from pc in ProductCategories select pc.Product).ToList(); }
    }

    private EntitySet<LocalizedCategory> _LocalizedCategories = new EntitySet<LocalizedCategory>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_LocalizedCategories", OtherKey = "CategoryID")]
    public ICollection<LocalizedCategory> LocalizedCategories
    {
        get { return _LocalizedCategories; }
        set { _LocalizedCategories.Assign(value); }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "products_types_localized")]
public class LocalizedCategory
{
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int LocalizedCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "products_types_id")]
    private int CategoryID;
    private EntityRef<Category> _Category = new EntityRef<Category>();
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_Category", ThisKey = "CategoryID")]
    public Category Category
    {
        get { return _Category.Entity; }
        set { _Category.Entity = value; }
    }

    [Column(Name = "country_id")]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to comment out everything from my View, so nothing there seems to influence this. The ViewModel is as simple as it looks, so shouldn't be anything there.

When reading this ( http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LinqToSQL5MinuteOVerview.ashx) I started suspecting it might be because I have no real foreign keys in the database and that I might need to use manual joins in my code. Is that correct? How would I go about it? Should I remove my mapping code from my domain model or is it something that I need to add/change to it?

Note: I've stripped parts of the code out that I don't think is relevant to make it cleaner for this question. Please let me know if something is missing.

EDIT: Gert Arnold solved the issue of all `Products` from the `Category` being queried one by one. However I'm still having the issue that all `Products` displayed on the page gets queried one by one.

This happens from my view code:

List.cshtml:

```
@model MaxFPS.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@foreach(var product in Model.Products) {
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", product);
}
```

ProductSummary.cshtml:

```
@model MaxFPS.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="item">
    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    @Model.Description
    @if (Model.ProductSubs.Count == 1)
    {
        using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductSubs.First().ProductSubID);
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            <input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>TODO: länk eller dropdown för produkter med varianter</p>
    }
    <h4>@Model.LowestPrice.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>
```

Is it something with .First() again? I tried .Take(1) but then I couldn't select the ID anyway...

EDIT: I tried adding some code to my repository to access the DataContext and this code to create a DataLoadOptions. But it still generates a query for each ProductSub.

```
var dlo = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Product>(p => p.ProductSubs);
localizedCategoriesRepository.DataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
var productsInCategory = localizedCategoriesRepository.LocalizedCategories.Where(lc => lc.CountryID == 1 && lc.Name == category)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(lc => lc.Category.ProductCategories)
    .Select(pc => pc.Product);
```

The SQL generated is slightly different though, and the order of the queries is also different.

For the queries that select ProductSub the DataLoadOptions-code generates variables named `@x1` and without them the variables are named `@p0`.

```
SELECT [t0].[products_id] AS [ProductID], [t0].[id] AS [ProductSubID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Price]
FROM [products_sub] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[products_id] = @x1
```

The difference in order for queries to me indicate that DataLoadOptions is in fact doing something, but not what I expect. What I'd expect is for it to generate something like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[products_id] AS [ProductID], [t0].[id] AS [ProductSubID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Price]
FROM [products_sub] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[products_id] = @x1 OR [t0].[products_id] = @x2 OR [t0].[products_id] = @x3 ... and so on
```

Comment: "I plan to add [Foreign Keys] later, but prefer not to do it right now to make migration easier"  Sounds like you're trading migration issues for programming issues.  Bite the bullet and add your foreign keys now.

Comment: I might have to do that, but I'm not sure how to go about it since the database is currently used live, so it can be tricky if I have to change stuff that affects the live website.

However I still want feedback on this issue. Will adding Foreign Keys solve my issue?

Comment: To my knowledge LINQ-to-SQL doesn't behave any differently whether the FKs are there or not (to do so it would have to query a bunch of system tables to find out about them), so that won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing is that it loads all products in the category, not just the 4 that are displayed. Which also seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `First()`. It triggers execution of the part before it and the part following it is fetched by lazy loading in separate queries. Tricky, hard to spot.

This is what you can do to prevent it and fetch everything in one shot:

```
LocalizedCategories.Where(lc => lc.CountryID == 1 && lc.Name == category)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(lc => lc.Category.ProductCategories)
    .Select (pc => pc.Product)
```

You should make the member `ProductCategories` public. I think it is also better to remove the derived properties `Category.Products` and `Product.Categories`, because I think they will trigger a query whenever their owner is materialized or addressed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you're on the right track. However with your code I'm getting 3 errors:

1 `Category does not contain a definition for ProductCategories and no extension method ProductCategories accepting a first argument of type Category could be found (missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
2 `Category.ProductCategories is inaccessible due to its protection level`
3 `The property or indexer Category.ProductCategories cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible`

I tried to change the code a bit, but still didn't get it working.

Comment: Of course. It wanted to copy the code behind `cat.Products` but took the wrong line. Modified it.

Comment: Thanks. That code worked, but sadly I'm still getting the same issue. If my domain objects are ok (which I'm not sure of) I think it might be something with lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to use that code directly though. Currently I have no direct accessor for LocalizedCategories. Should I create a Repository for them? My only way of accessing them now is through categoriesRepository.Categories.

Comment: The only way to get everything in one query is using "real" navigation properties. A member like `Category.Products` in a linq query will give an exception like "The member 'Product.Categories' has no supported translation to SQL." So creating a repository for `LocalizedCategories` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again. I've now created a repository for `LocalizedCategories` and the results with your code is a big improvement over the earlier results! Now I only get 1 SQL query for each `Product` displayed instead of all `Products` in the `Category`. However, since I'm going to display a lot of `Products` I'd still like to get all data for them in a single query. I'll update my original question in a moment.

Comment: I don't really understand why this keeps happening. "My" query should get the products in one shot. The `ToList()` in assigning the products to the view model should emit on SQL query (can you confirm that?). If more queries fire afterwards it must be from these properties `Category.Products` etc.

Comment: The remaining problem seems to be that `ProductSubs` is lazy loaded. When I change/remove these lines the extra queries are not triggered: `@if (Model.ProductSubs.Count == 1)` `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductSubs.First().ProductSubID);` `@Model.LowestPrice.ToString("c")`. I've read about using `.Include("ProductSubs")` but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Since this is linq-to-sql you should use [`DataLoadOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok. I'm new to this, so I'm still having issues to separate what is what. I managed to write code for DataLoadOptions, but it didn't work. I'll add the code at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Thanks to you and some more research/trial and error I solved the last bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661398/how-to-map-linq-to-sql-to-enable-eager-loading-return-entityset-or-icollection/12721210#12721210